# How to use request.POST.get() with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, django

I don't even know how to phrase this, and I'm sure it's a ridiculously stupid question, but here goes.

On my modal's html page, I'm doing:

```
var user = $("#signup-form").serialize();
$.post("/signup/",
               { user : user,
                 csrfmiddlewaretoken : '{{ csrf_token }}' }
```

So now, in views.py, I have no idea how to get the aspects of user (firstname, lastname, etc, in this case).

```
user = request.POST.get('user')
```

But there doesn't seem to be a way to pull the other keys out, if that makes any sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, it looks like form data is serialized inside the `user` argument which may not be what you want.

A typical pattern is to include all fields inside the form (including `csrfmiddlewaretoken` as a hidden field), and send the serialized form as data. E.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}"/>
```

Then in javascript:

```
var form_data = $("#signup-form").serialize();
$.post("/signup/", form_data);
```

In the Django view, you can extract then extract form fields from  `request.POST` directly, or construct a [Django Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/) to handle this for you.

Comment: Thanks. I was doing the above because someone on another question of mine said to. But this works!